# JQuery: Event not binding to table created dynamically; even using $(document).on

Tags: javascript, jquery

In some cases, Table is generated dynamically in JSP; but following Jquery is not getting executed :

```
$(document).on("click", "a.fileDownload", function () {

   $.fileDownload($(this).prop('href'))
    .done(function () {  })
    .fail(function () {  });

    return false; //Critical to stop the click event which will trigger a normal file download
});

FileDownload Plugin: https://github.com/johnculviner/jquery.fileDownload
```

For debugging, I open firebug and checked code and found following:

```
<a class="fileDownload" href="http://test.myportalen.de/bin/my/Filereader.svc/GetDocument/id/1232312/name/qwerty.pdf">qwerty.pdf</a>
```

(In firebug, when i put space in Anchor Text and revert to original then the event gets fired. Could anyone explain the reason and solution? Unable to create fiddle)

Update: JSP for reference

```
<c:when test="${document.extension eq 'pdf'}">
  <a href="${document.link}" class="fileDownload">
    <c:choose>
       <c:when test="${document.docType}">
          ${fn:trim(document.docTitle)}
       </c:when>  
       <c:otherwise>
          ${fn:trim(document.docTitle)}.${fn:trim(document.extension)}
       </c:otherwise>
      </c:choose>
    </a>
```

Comment: Does anyone really use Firebug any more? Wow!

Comment: Thanks. It still helps me a lot for coding, real time results and debugging :) . Any idea on query?

Comment: Is it possible to share a fiddle demo ?

Comment: You should really do your testing in Chrome. MUCH better development tools. Also FF is known for not following standards.

Comment: @ScottMarcus: OK Thanks for suggestion.

Comment: @RayonDabre: No unable to create this issue in fiddle.

Comment: @guest271314
It is plugin,  attached link. No issues with plugin as at many places it is working fine.

Comment: if it isn't reproducible in a fiddle then something else in your code is affecting

Comment: @Santiago: 
How can i create dynamic code in fiddle, does it supports JSP? For static code it is already working fine as i said. This is how it looks: https://jsfiddle.net/5mL3z8zk/

Comment: There is something I don't understand... How can a JSP be sometimes dynamically generated. It is once generated server side then sent to the client. Finished !  What are you saying by "dynamically generated" ? Where does come your JS code ? Is it an external resource loaded inside a chunk of JSP ? Are you adding your <a> with some Ajax or else ?

Comment: The above code is getting executed on page load but related script is not getting loaded the reason when i click on link nothing happens.